# Identity permutation is an even permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

If we attempt to write $(1)$ as a product of odd transpositions, say $(1)=\underbrace{(a_1 a_2)(a_3 a_4)...(a_m a_n)}_{k\text{ times}}$, where $k$ is odd, then what is the property of a product of an even number of transpositions, such that we arrive at the contradiction that $(1)$ cannot be written as a product of k transpositions?

I still don't have a lot of intuition for symmetric groups.

Comment: The identity permutation is clearly even, since it’s the product of $0$ transpositions, and $0$ is even. If you’ve proved the theorem that every permutation is either even or odd, there’s no reason to repeat the proof for this particular permutation.

Comment: The issue is that $(1)$ can be expressed as an arbitrary number of transpositions. The goal is to show that these must always be in even quantity.

Comment: As I said, that’s just a special case of the more general theorem that every permutation is unambiguously either even or odd. I take it that you’ve not yet proved that result?

Comment: On the other hand, proving it for identity would immediately imply that it is true in general! But I don't know whether that is a particularly helpful observation.